# how to read if radio button checked and save it as 1 with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button, selecteditem, radio-group

I have 3 radio buttons:

```
<div id="step-1">
    <h2 class="StepTitle">
        <label style="font-weight: bold; color: #662819;" id="frage1"></label>
    </h2>
    <br />

    <input type="radio" name="group1" id="antwort1" value="" onmousedown="this.__chk = this.checked" onclick="if (this.__chk) this.checked = false" />
    <label id="antwort1fuerFrage1"></label>
    <br />
    <br />

    <input type="radio" name="group1" id="antwort2" value="" onmousedown="this.__chk = this.checked" onclick="if (this.__chk) this.checked = false" />
    <label id="antwort2fuerFrage1"></label>
    <br />
    <br />

    <input type="radio" name="group1" id="antwort3" value="" onmousedown="this.__chk = this.checked" onclick="if (this.__chk) this.checked = false" />
    <label id="antwort3fuerFrage1"></label>
</div>
```

I am trying to read if radio button is checked, and save a value (need 1 or/ 0) like this:

```
var frage1 = document.getElementById("frage1").innerHTML;
var antwort1 = document.getElementById("antwort1");
var antwort2 = document.getElementById("antwort2");
var antwort3 = document.getElementById("antwort3");

antwort1 = $('input[id="antwort1"]:checked').val();
antwort2 = $('input[id="antwort2"]:checked').val();
antwort3 = $('input[id="antwort3"]:checked').val();
```

antwort 1, 2, 3 are undefined. I need to get `0` or `1`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could just use `.length` since you're querying IDs:

```
antwort1 = $('#antwort1:checked').length;
antwort2 = $('#antwort2:checked').length;
antwort3 = $('#antwort3:checked').length;
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop) like

```
antwort1 = $('input[id="antwort1"]').prop();
antwort2 = $('input[id="antwort2"]').prop();
antwort3 = $('input[id="antwort3"]').prop();
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VXP5z/1/)

Comment: This will always return 1 as even jq empty object is truly

Comment: @A.Wolff is correct, this answer will not produce the correct result. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/VXP5z/

Comment: The updated answer remains wrong. Recommend simply deleting, there's a correct answer posted.

Answer (score 2):

You could do like this:

```
var antwort1 = $('#antwort1:checked').length;
var antwort2 = $('#antwort2:checked').length;

console.log(antwort1);
console.log(antwort2);
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/vGuUc/)